# Node.js Express does not delete secure cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, httponly

My backend (Node.js + express.js) uses the following code to delete a cookie:

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  res.clearCookie('access_token', { domain:'localhost', path: '/', httpOnly: true, secure: true })
  .redirect('http://localhost:4200/login')
});
```

The problem is when I made the cookie secure the previous code no longer deletes the cookie no matter how I visit the url.

Comment: Is `clearCookie` called with the same arguments as `cookie`? As well, have you tried to set `cookie` once again with a time equal to 1?

Comment: Yes, clearCookie has the same arguments as cookie. How do I do that exactly?

Comment: `res.cookie('access_token','', { ...yourOptions, expires: new Date(1) })`

Comment: @necromos that did not help. Maybe the issue is that the frontend is running on HTTPS Port 80 and Backend over HTTPS on Port 443?